# Web components and performance

Tags: web-development, html5

I am having trouble learning about the impact of web components and shadow DOM on the browser, specifically related to repaint.

I remember reading at one point that the shadow DOM nodes have encapsulated repaints, which greatly enhances performance, but I cannot find any articles about this, so it seems like speculation.

Can anyone tell me how web components and performance are related?

Comment: It's not speculation at all; it's just not true.  I did a quick Google Search and found [several](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/) [articles](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-201/) and [tutorials](http://www.sitepoint.com/the-basics-of-the-shadow-dom/) about Shadow DOM.  All of them talk about encapsulation, but *very few talk about performance.*  The [ones that do talk about performance](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/web-components-arent-ready-production-yet/) say that *Shadow DOM decreases performance,* not increases it.

Comment: Are you confusing Shadow DOM with the "virtual DOM" that things like React use?

Comment: Perhaps.  From what i understand, the polyfills can kill performance.

Comment: I may be confusing with virtual dom (react), but i am unsure as to how virtual dom would prevent complete repaints?

Comment: I haven't read anything about native web component implementations having worse performance.  The polyfills are a different story.  Can you share your source regarding that?  I don't see that in your article @RobertHarvey